# Where can I find the Sentinel-2 HTML folder in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: sentinel-2, sen2cor

I'm using sen2cor 2.8 to make the atmospheric correction to Sentinel-2 L1C imagery downloaded from google cloud storage. I'm getting an error from sen2cor because it uses a file contained in the HTML directory which seems to be missing in the GCP bucket. I used this [Downloading Sentinel-2 data from Google Cloud Storage with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293024/downloading-sentinel-2-data-from-google-cloud-storage-with-python) to build the .SAFE folder.

How can I download the HTML folder? or How can I use sen2cor without this folder?